# How do you create a Parts Order/any transaction through a RESTlet in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Currently I am able to send data to NS through a Restlet but it seems that I am only able to create a customrecord type but cannot seem to find out how to create a non custom record.

How do I find the name or endpoints. I have added my restlet to the SuiteScript but that is as far as I got.

### EDIT

```
PartOrderREST.postRESTlet = function(dataIn) {
nlapiLogExecution('audit', 'PartOrderREST.postRESTlet', 'JSON=' + JSON.stringify(dataIn));
try {
    var nsFields = new PO_OBJ_FIELDS();
    var recPO = nlapiCreateRecord(nsFields.purchaseorder, {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
    recPO.setFieldValue('entity', dataIn['entity']);
    recPO.setFieldValue('name', dataIn['name']);
    recPO.setFieldValue('employee', dataIn['employee']);
    recPO.setFieldValue('class', dataIn['class']);
    recPO.setFieldValue('location', dataIn['location']);
    recPO.setFieldValue('exchangerate', '2.15');
    recPO.setFieldValue('currency', '2.15');
    recPO.setFieldValue('trandate', dataIn['trandate']);
} catch(err) {
    nlapiLogExecution('audit', 'PartOrderREST.postRESTlet', err.message);
    return {'error': 'error 1' + err.message}
}

try {
    recPO.selectNewLineItem('item');
    recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
    recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', dataIn['item']);
    recPO.commitLineItem('item');
    recPO.selectNewLineItem('item');
    recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
    recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', dataIn['item']);
    recPO.commitLineItem('item');

    var idPO = nlapiSubmitRecord(recPO, true);
    return {'nswoid': idPO};
} catch(err) {
    nlapiLogExecution('audit', 'PartOrderREST.postRESTlet', err.message);
    return {'error': 'error 2' + err.message}
}
};
```

This issue is that I get an error saying something along the lines of need line item to create record. I try adding the item to the purchase order but it is removed before it is submitted.

The first part of the code in the first try statement seems to work. I does not seem to successfully add a line item of 'item' given the specific nsid of the item I want to add to the order. 'item' is said to be the only required element of the Purchase order.

Comment: Can you please be more clear/specific?

Comment: @NetSuiteGuru I made an update. I am trying to make a purchase order through a restlet and can almost make one but cannot seem to add an item to the transaction. It never commits the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you hardcode the value in your restlet to see if your restlet works without parameterised data?

I have tried below code and it works:

```
var recPO=nlapiCreateRecord('purchaseorder', {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
recPO.setFieldValue('customform',formId);
recPO.setFieldValue('entity', entityId);
recPO.setFieldValue('name', 'Name');
recPO.setFieldValue('employee', employeeId);

recPO.selectNewLineItem('item');
recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item',itemId); 
recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', 1);
recPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity',100);
recPO.commitLineItem('item');

var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(recPO, true);
```

If you still get error after hardcoding the values then there might be some script deployed on PurchaseOrder throwning the error. You can check the scripts deployed on record by following below path:-
Customization->Scripting->Scripted Records->Purchase Order

Comment: That absolutely worked. But I am curious. Do the IDs need to be numbers or strings?